# Windows phone 8.1: Recording screen outside application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

This is primary my first post here. The question is about the screen recording feature that has been added to the windows phone 8.1 version of the MediaCapture API.

As can be seen here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt282147.aspx

Now the question is whether Windows phone 8.1 allows to perform a screen recording as a background task or not?

I mean, the feature is completely useless if it only can be used inside the application UI and not anywhere else.

To clarify my question : If you build an application that video capture the screen, is it possible to record outside the application UI e.g. a game or another application? - If so where can I find any resources as guidelines.

Thanks in advance, I would appreciate any kind of help, I could possibly get.

Comment: That article appears to only relate to universal apps on windows 10 mobile devices, and not windows phone 8.1

Comment: Did you just try it out? Can't find any information, but you probably won't be able to record outside of your own UI.

Comment: I have tried many ways but nothing works. Maybe that API only support inside our app.